# Mixing swift and objective-c in WatchKitExtension

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, ios-extensions

I am getting following warnings and errors while in my `WatchKit` extension:

```
Warning: no rule to process file 'App-Bridging-Header.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture x86_64

/Users/janusz/Desktop/Repositories/RunnerAppWatch/Source/WormholeMessanger.swift:12:20: Use of unresolved identifier 'MMWormhole'
```

[image: Bridge Header]

It's also listed in Compiled Sources section.

Everything works fine when I delete the `WatchKit` Extension, but once I add it back I am getting errors again. 
So the question is: how to make bridging header work with the `WatchKit` Extension? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bridging header must not be included in the `Compiled Sources` section.  In general, headers should not be added to `Compiled Sources`.  So, remove that and it should work.